# Python lxml-based XSL transformation does not work

Tags: python, xml, xslt, lxml

I have a problem performing XSL transformation from XML file to tab-delimeted file using lxml library.

First about what it transforms. I'm transforming slightly modified Qt translation files, root is **TS**, a number of **contexts**, every context contains a number of **messages**, which contain values **source** and **translation** which are required, and **translatorcomment** is optional

```
<TS version="2.1" language="ru_RU">
<context>
    <message>
        <source>TextLabel1</source>
        <translatorcomment>Some comment</translatorcomment>
        <translation>Перевод TextLabel1</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <source>TextLabel2</source>
        <translation>Перевод TextLabel2</translation>
    </message>
</context>
<context>
    <message>
    ...
    </message>
</context>
</TS>
```

Now how it transforms. I need two transformations, to simple HTML table and to tab-delimeted file, to be opened in Excel (it's really easy for Tech writers)

For HTML table it was almost easy, very common task (take notice how optional fields are solved, maybe more elegant way exists).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="TS">
    <table align="left" style="font-family:arial;font-size:12px" border="2">
      <!-- Table header -->
      <tr>
        <th>Source</th>
        <th>Translation</th>
        <th>Comment</th>
      </tr>
      <!-- Iterate over context/message -->
      <xsl:for-each select="context">
        <xsl:for-each select="message">
          <tr>
            <!-- One row cells -->
            <td align="left">
              <xsl:value-of select="source" />
            </td>
            <td align="left">
              <xsl:value-of select="translation" />
            </td>
            <!-- Third, conditional cell -->
            <xsl:if test="translatorcomment">
              <td align="left">
                <xsl:value-of select="translatorcomment" />
              </td>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="not(translatorcomment)">
              <td></td>
            </xsl:if>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For tab-delimeted file it was slightly complicated. Changed output method is text here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="TS">
    <!-- Header. Put tab after every value -->
    <xsl:text>Source&#x9;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>Translation&#x9;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>Comment&#x9;</xsl:text>
    <!-- End of line -->
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- Iterate over values -->
    <xsl:for-each select="context">
      <xsl:for-each select="message">
        <xsl:value-of select="source" />
        <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="translation" />
        <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="translatorcomment">
          <xsl:value-of select="translatorcomment" />
          <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not(translatorcomment)">
          <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <!-- End of line -->
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How I know both of them are working? I checked it on [Free Online XSL transformer](https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html), and both providing completely correct results. Yeah, first I wrote transformations, and then started to look how to perform them offline, which is appeared not easy. We're using C++ and Python, and Python seems to be easiest way as it has a lot of libraries, does not require compilation etc.

Now, if you did not lost patience, about my problem and Python code I use.
I'm using the most common tool for transformation, lxml, method was discussed here on SO many times

```
    import lxml.etree as et

    xml_file = et.parse(input_xml)
    xslt_file = et.parse(transform_xsl)
    transform = et.XSLT(xslt_file)
    transformed = transform(xml_file)
    with open(self.output, "w") as out_file:
        print((et.tostring(transformed, pretty_print=True)).decode("utf-8"), file=out_file)
```

I'm performing my first transformation to HTML without any problems. Second transformation, to tab-delimited file, fails with exception from LXML

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xsl_transform.py", line 137, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "xsl_transform.py", line 127, in main
    xsl_transformer.transform()
  File "xsl_transform.py", line 86, in transform
    print((et.tostring(transformed, pretty_print=True)).decode("utf-8"), file=out_file)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Apparently, lxml.etree._XSLTResultTree type returns None when trying to convert to string. Other try, `print(str(transformed))` also failed with the error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xab' in position 17440: character maps to <undefined>`

So, `transformed` contains something but it could not converted to string. Maybe problem with encoding, even though all files in UTF-8

Comment: Does the method http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._XSLTResultTree-class.html#write_output work for you e.g. `transformed.write_output(out_file)`? Note that the method was introduced in lxml 4 I think (http://lxml.de/4.0/changes-4.0.0.html)

Comment: It seems I have earlier version: AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._XSLTResultTree' object has no attribute 'write_output'